# Multiple xlBetween Operators in format conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update 1 column with three colors based on the cell value. For some reason when this runs it only does the first xl between and ignores the other 2.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  With mybook.Worksheets(1)

'Create range object
Set MyRange = Range("Z1:Z65000")
'Delete previous conditional formats
MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
'Add first rule
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="65", Formula2:="74.9"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)
End With
'Add second rule
 With mybook.Worksheets(1)
 Set MyRange = Range("Z1:Z65000")
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="75", Formula2:="99.9"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
End With
'Add third rule
 With mybook.Worksheets(1)
 Set MyRange = Range("Z1:Z65000")
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="100"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one line for each code you write, the following code should be working for you `MyRange.FormatConditions(MyRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority`

So the correct order should be:

```
With Sheet1

Set MyRange = Range("Z1:Z65000")
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
       Formula1:="75", Formula2:="99.9"
MyRange.FormatConditions(MyRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
End With
```

Sometime using VBA recorder will help you detect which part you are missing.